# Completely uninstall Eclipse 4.7 version in RHEL 7.4 Maipo

Tags: eclipse, uninstallation, rhel

I'm trying to uninstall the current version of Eclipse IDE in my RHEL machine by simply deleting all the files like:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.eclipse
sudo rm -rf ~/eclipse-workspace
```

I also tried

```
sudo yum remove 'eclipse*'
```

However, these didn't seem to solve the purpose.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications on Linux systems are most often installed using so-called packages, which are managed by a package management system. In the case of RHEL, packages use the RPM format, and the package manager of choice is a tool called `yum`.

Both installation and removal of software (packages) should be done using `yum`, so as to allow the package management system keep track of all installed files and current status. Therefore, you shouldn't try to remove software by simply deleting files from the file system. Instead, use the `yum` command. See the RHEL System Admin Guide for a detailed explanation of how to use `yum` to search, install, upgrade, and remove packages: [Working with Packages](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sec-working_with_packages).

You have tried the correct command (`yum remove <package-name>`), but you need to use the correct package name. On RHEL 7.4, the latest version of Eclipse is available as a part of the DevTools channel, and the package name is `rh-eclipse47` (see [Enabling the Red Hat Developer Tools Repositories](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_tools/2018.1/html/using_eclipse/eclipse_4_7_2#enabling_the_red_hat_developer_tools_repositories)). Note that you may have also installed an older version,  which would be, for example, `rh-eclipse46`.

To find out what is the name of the package you have installed, you can run, for example, the following command:

```
yum list installed | grep eclipse
```

There is also the possibility that you installed the software not from an RPM package but manually, e.g. from a `.tar.gz` file distrubuted from eclipse.org. If that's the case, you will need to use the uninstaller program supplied with that distribution of the software.

Comment: Hey @Robert Kratky Thanks for your reply, that was very informative.
I tried the above steps as well but they didn't work find, which should have had, and this makes me interested in figuring what mistakes I did. However, I will try that once again.
In the meanwhile I tried removing the directory where it was installed. This seems to work, is it so?
Thanks.

Comment: Also when I run the code 

`yum list installed | grep eclipse`

This writes the following: 

`Repository nodesource is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository nodesource-source is listed more than once in the configuration`

Not able to understand what does this mean. If you can help in this as well.

Comment: Ad removing directory: I really can't tell whether you really removed all parts of Eclipse because I don't know what method you used to install it. If the software was installed from an RPM package, then it's very likely that other files still remain on the system. If it was installed using some other (manual) method, then it might be all that was needed.

Comment: Ad the message from `yum`: That's unrelated. The fact that no other output is seen means that your Eclipse was not installed from any RPM package that would have the string `eclipse` in its name. The message itself is harmless. If you wish to investigate, look at the repo definition files in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`. See [Configuring Yum and Yum Repositories](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sec-Configuring_Yum_and_Yum_Repositories) for detailed docs.

Comment: Thanks @Robert Kratky, that was very helpful though it was not quite exact the solution. Theoretically yes, that may be the correct answer but I having installed it manually, so removed all the files manually and yes that worked, even cleaned the `~/.bashrc`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Write command as:

```
rpm -qa|grep eclipse
```

This  will give a list of installed packages. Remove all the packages by giving below command:

```
rpm -e *package-name*
```

Done!!!